# Help with an image I'm assuming is cryptic

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

[image: Image I need help with]

Got sent this on Discord, and I need help with identifying if it's like anything secretive or etc.

Here's a zoomed version of that string:
[image: string]
`a67340824040cbf489c23ec04eb88c3e`

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Comment: It looks like it! Have you tried overlaying the right and left images? Sometimes you can add the rgb values.

Comment: @DrXorile Yeah, but no avail.

Comment: The height of the strip of pixels at the bottom of the image is the same as the size of the large pixels that make up the images (7x7). I think it has something to do with image manipulation

Comment: @Adam Could be that, but that doesn't explain the string above the strip of pixels.

Comment: Do you have a high res image that clearly shows the horizontal line in the bottom? I would guess it's needed to solve this.

Comment: @Adam What? Not only is that strip 6 pixels tall, not 7, the images are much taller, even when looking at the "apparent" pixels. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @Christian yea, I noticed. I didn't want to use an extra comment to correct myself. The "blocks" are not a fixed size and vary between 6 and 7 pixels. I just so happened to move the strip over the 6 pixel high blocks then counted the size of a 7x7 block. I will use this comment to say that there is noticeable noise in the image, if that helps anyone. There is also a random colour change in the image at the lower third which is clearly unnatural however I don't know what to make of it

Answer (score 0):

The picture seems to be a scene of a dug up underground area. As you can see in the given picture, the prominent colours are the shades of blue and brown. Actually blue and brown are opposite colours of each other.

The upper half of the picture has been covered up in a *opposite colour filter* that converted brown into blue, it's negative counterpart. Notice a small number of green pixels around the *terminator line* between the two regions. That seems to depict a small amount of green grass in the pit. But it is unfiltered by the *opposite colour filter* because opposite of green is violet but there is no visible violet region in the picture.

You can check the opposite colours [here](https://www.colortools.net/color_complementary.html).